# Function returning REF CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have package like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE product_package AS 
   TYPE t_ref_cursor to IS REF CURSOR; 

   FUNCTION get_products_ref_cursor RETURN t_ref_cursor; 
END product_package; 


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY product_package AS 
   FUNCTION get_products_ref_cursor is RETURN t_ref_cursor IS 
      products_ref_cursor t_ref_cursor; 

   BEGIN 
      OPEN products_ref_cursor FOR
         SELECT product_id, name, price FROM Products; 
      RETURN products_ref_cursor; 
   END get_products_ref_cursor;
END product_package;
```

My question is, how can I use function *get_products_ref_cursor* (ref cursor) to get list of products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare 
  type rec is record(produc_id number, name varchar2(x), price number);
  type l_rec is table of rec; 
  v_l_rec l_rec; 
  v_cursor product_package.t_ref_cursor;
begin 
  v_cursor  := product_package.get_products_ref_cursor;
  fetch v_cursor  bulk collect into v_l_rec; 
  -- in v_l_rec is list collection of products.
  close v_cursor;
end;
```

Code wasn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language or tool from which you are calling the function.  If you are calling from SQL*Plus, you can just

```
print <variable_name>
```

where  is the name of the PL/SQL bind variable to which you returned the function's results.

If you are in PL/SQL, you need to write a loop where you fetch... exit when %NOTFOUND... etc.  There are a million examples, including the PL/SQL Users Guide.

If you are in Java, you cast the cursor object as a ResultSet and fetch its results in a loop.

Other languages will have other ways, but they mostly all entail looping through the cursor and fetching the results.

So... it depends on the caller's language.